# how to pass information to thread during runtime?

Tags: c++, windows, multithreading

How do I pass data to another thread within the same process? I'm writing in c++ for windows 7 os. Consider the following thread for example:

```
DWORD WINAPI MyThreadFunction(LPVOID lpParam){
    while(true){
        //Do the thread's job here
        if(gotReturnInstruction()){
           //release memory etc.
           break;
        }
    }
    return 0;
}
```

This thread does its job as long as some other thread tells it to return. I have the handle to the thread, which I obtain from the 'CreateThread()' function.
How do I pass the message to the thread (in this case the stop instruct)?

Comment: usually you pass in the params a handle to a event, and inside the while(true) you check if the event is signaled to stop the execution

Comment: @JoãoAugusto What kind of event are you talking about? Can you give link to documentation maybe?

Comment: Check, CreateEvent, SetEvent and WaitForSingleObject functions

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You don't "push" a stop instruction to a thread.  Instead, that thread needs to "poll" for a stop instruction.  If the thread is in a loop and performing work all the time, it could check for the stop instruction as simply as checking a global variable `bool stopThread` that is set by the main thread when it wants it to stop.

However, it will boost your CPU usage to 100% if the thread just sits in a `while (true)` loop doing nothing but checking this global variable.  In this case, call `WaitForSingleObject` on an [event](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/ms686915%28v=vs.85%29.aspx) which sleeps your thread until the main thread "signals the event" and wakes it up.